# Python - Multiply matrices with different numbers of columns

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I'm trying to multiple two matrices, A and B, where B has more columns than A using python and numpy preferably.

Example:

```
A = numpy.matrix([[2,3,15],[5,8,12],[1,13,4]], dtype=numpy.object)
B = numpy.matrix([[2,15,6,15,8,14],[17,19,17,7,18,14],[24,14,0,24,2,11]], dtype=numpy.object)

( A*B ) = [[415,297,63,411,100,235],[434,395,166,419,208,314], [319,318,227,202,250,240]]
```

I've found some examples if they are arrays but none if they are matrices. Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you actually try this? It works fine here:

```
import numpy as np

def main():
    A = np.matrix([[2,3,15],[5,8,12],[1,13,4]], dtype=np.object)
    B = np.matrix([[2,15,6,15,8,14],[17,19,17,7,18,14],[24,14,0,24,2,11]], dtype=np.object)

    C = ( A*B ) % 26 #  = [[25,11,11,21,22,1],[18,5,10,3,0,2], [7,6,19,20,16,6]]
    print(C)
    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Prints:

```
[[25 11 11 21 22 1]
 [18 5 10 3 0 2]
 [7 6 19 20 16 6]]
```

Comment: I guess it was an example of a larger issue, as I was trying with a different matrix. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You could also use the dot product.

```
numpy.dot(A,B)
```

It outputs the same answer that you want.